# Session State will not update

Tags: asp.net, web

I am trying to write a page in asp.net to update an user object from Session state and I am running into a problem putting the object back into the Session state

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public partial class UpdateAccount : System.Web.UI.Page
{
cAccount account;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["account"] != null)
    {
        account = (cAccount)Session["account"];

        lblID.Text = account.AccountNumber.ToString();
        txtEmail.Text = account.Email;
        txtFirstName.Text = account.FirstName;
        txtLastName.Text = account.LastName;
        lblArtist.Text = account.Artist.ToString();

        if (account.CardNumber != "")
        {
            ddlCardType.SelectedValue = account.CardType;
            txtNumber.Text = account.CardNumber;
            ddlMonth.SelectedIndex = (account.ExpMonth - 1);
            txtExpYear.Text = account.ExpYear.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            ddlCardType.SelectedIndex = 0;
            txtNumber.Text = "";
            ddlMonth.SelectedIndex = 0;
            txtExpYear.Text = "";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblID.Text = "-1";
        txtEmail.Text = "";
        txtFirstName.Text = "";
        txtLastName.Text = "";
        lblArtist.Text = "";

        ddlCardType.SelectedIndex = 0;
        txtNumber.Text = "";
        ddlMonth.SelectedIndex = 0;
        txtExpYear.Text = "";
    }
}

protected void btnUpdateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtOldPass.Text == account.Password)
    {
        lblOldPass.Text = "";
        account.setDetails(txtEmail.Text, txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text);
        Session["account"] = account;
        Response.Redirect("Accounts.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        lblOldPass.Text = "Password Incorrect";
    }

}
}
```

This is the code i am using on load, and on update. These are the only spots session state is used.

EDIT

The exact problem I am getting is the updated object does not get saved to the Session State. The old one remains on page load of this page and the page I am using to display the object. The Form_Load method works the same in both.

Comment: Can you describe what the your problem actually is please? It's not clear from the question you've posted. Are you getting an exception thrown, is the account information not updating as expected?

Comment: @RMDan Do you need to check `if (Session["account"] != null)` at each PostBack?. I think you should check if `!Page.IsPostback` before your `if (Session["account"] != null)`

Comment: @r.piesnikowski I have tried that, but it brings up different errors(account object is not available to other methods). Adding that to the other page makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what is happening here is:

1. User navigates to page:

   - Page_Load fires, picks up the details from the account object stored in session.
2. User fills in form details, clicks the update user button:

   - Page_Load fires, picks up the details from the account object stored in session, *overwriting the user's entered details*.
   - btnUpdateUser_Click fires, sets details based on the current values in the form controls, which by now have been set to the old values.

So there's nothing wrong the click event handler, but the Page_Load activity needs to handle the post back better, i.e.:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    if (Session["account"] != null)
    {
    .... the rest of your stuff here ....
    }
}
```